# php pagination numbered page links

Tags: php, pagination

This is a pagination code used for the navigation, any ideas how to get this code to display simply a numbered list of the pages as links?

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
   $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} 
else {
   $pageno = 1;
}
if(isset($_GET['niche']))
{


$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM studies WHERE niche = '{$_GET['niche']}'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
}


$query_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $query_data[0];
$rows_per_page = 4;
$lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
$pageno = (int)$pageno;
if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
   $pageno = $lastpage;
}
if ($pageno < 1) {
   $pageno = 1;
} // if
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;
$query = "SELECT * FROM studies WHERE niche = '{$_GET['niche']}' $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

and...

```
if ($pageno == 1) {
   echo "<div class='container'>FIRST PREV ";
} else {
   echo "<div class='container'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=1&niche={$_GET['niche']}'>FIRST</a> ";
   $prevpage = $pageno-1;
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=$prevpage&niche={$_GET['niche']}'>PREV</a> ";
} // if
echo " ( Page $pageno of $lastpage ) ";
if ($pageno == $lastpage) {
   echo " NEXT LAST</div><br />";
} else {
   $nextpage = $pageno+1;
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=$nextpage&niche={$_GET['niche']}'>NEXT</a> ";
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=$lastpage&niche={$_GET['niche']}'>LAST</a></div><br /> ";
} // if
?>
```

Comment: Although you posted this 20 minutes ago, I'd like to point out for a 3rd time that you don't want to use a $_GET request inside a SQL query. Doing so could destroy your entire database.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rows_per_page);

if($totalpages >= 1){ $pagelinkcount = 1; } else { $pagelinkcount = 0; }

while($pagelinkcount <= $totalpages && $totalpages > 1) {

     echo "<a href=\"/page/{$pagelinkcount}\">{$pagelinkcount}</a>&nbsp;";

     $pagelinkcount++;

}
```

On a side note, as Ian Elliot pointed out in the comments for your question, using $_GET in an SQL query leaves your database VERY vulnerable, and is thus considered an extremely insecure coding practice.  You should escape and parse the $_GET data that you need diligently before passing it to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I've been using for pagination for a while. It returns nothing if there's only one page, returns up to 15 pages with numbers, then adds a dropdown that lets you skip to any 10th page when there are more than 15 pages. It relies on some prev/next images, but you can easily take that out.

```
function paginate( $items_per_page, $number_of_results ) {

    if( isset( $_REQUEST['page'] ) ) {
        $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $url = htmlentities( preg_replace( '/(\?|&)page=[\d]+/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'&' );

    $html = '';
    $numbers_html = '';
    $navigation_html = '';
    if( $number_of_results > $items_per_page ) {
        $html .= '<div class="pagination">';
        if( $page == 1 or $page == '1' ) {
            $numbers_html .= '<img src="images/prev.png" alt="&larr; prev" class="inactive" /> - ';
        } else {
            $numbers_html .= '<a href="'.$url.'/page'.($page-1).'"><img src="images/prev.png" alt="&larr; prev" /></a> - ';
        }
        $count = 0;
        $total_pages = ceil( $number_of_results / $items_per_page )-1;
        while( $count <= $total_pages ) {
            $count++;
            if( $total_pages > 12 and floor($count / 10) != floor($page / 10) ) {
                while( $count < $total_pages and floor($count / 10) != floor($page / 10) ) {
                    if( $count == 1 ) {
                        $endpage = 9;
                    } elseif( $count + 9 < $total_pages ) {
                        $endpage = $count + 9;
                    } else {
                        $endpage = $total_pages + 1;
                    }
                    $ten_group = floor( $count / 10 );
                    if( $ten_group == 0 ) {
                        $navigation_html .= '<option value="'.$url.'page='.$count.'">page 1</option>';
                    } else {
                        $navigation_html .= '<option value="'.$url.'page='.$count.'">page '.($ten_group*10).'</option>';
                    }
                    $count += 10;
                }
                $count -= 2;
            } else {
                if( $page == $count ) {
                    $numbers_html .= '<span class="current">'.$count.'</span>';
                    if( $count == 1 ) {
                        $endpage = 9;
                    } elseif( $count + 9 < $total_pages ) {
                        $endpage = $count + 9;
                    } else {
                        $endpage = $total_pages + 1;
                    }
                    if( $total_pages > 15 ) {
                        $ten_group = floor( $count / 10 );
                        if( $ten_group == 0 ) {
                            $navigation_html .= '<option value="'.$url.'page='.$count.'" selected="selected">page 1</option>';
                        } else {
                            $navigation_html .= '<option value="'.$url.'page='.$count.'" selected="selected">page '.($ten_group*10).'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $numbers_html .= '<a href="'.$url.'/page'.$count.'">'.$count.'</a>';
                }
                if( ( $total_pages > 12 and $count % 10 == 9 ) or $count == $total_pages+1 ) {
                } else {
                    $numbers_html .= ' - ';
                }
            }
        }
        if( $page != $count ) {
            $numbers_html .= ' - <a href="'.$url.'/page'.($page+1).'"><img src="images/next.png" alt="next &rarr;" /></a>';
        } else {    
            $numbers_html .= ' - <img src="images/next.png" alt="next &rarr;" class="inactive"/>';
        }
        $count++;
        $html .= '<div class="pagination_numbers">'.$numbers_html.'</div>';
        if( $navigation_html ) {
            $html .= '<div class="pagination_navigation">skip to: <select onchange="window.location=this.value">'.$navigation_html.'</select> of '.($total_pages+1).'</div>';
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many pages to display, you might want to consider "logarithmic" page naviagtion, as I describe in my answer here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

(Sample PHP code only handles the pagination display - not the DB query).